# Integrating AWS Cognito and Azure AD: Allowing access for any Microsoft User without preloading accounts?

Tags: azure, amazon-cognito

This is a problem I'm currently facing. Just to clarify, I have a good understanding of AWS Cognito, but Azure is not within my expertise, and I'm feeling a bit lost in that territory.

My goal is to enable every Microsoft user, both personal and corporate (AD), to access my platform using a 'Log In With Microsoft' button.

In my user pool, I've set up two federated identity providers, one using SAML and the other using OIDC. In Azure AD B2C, I've created the App registration, and I've successfully configured the connection to Cognito. (If I use a user from the AD, I can log in without issues.) However, there's a requirement that's causing a hurdle: **I must pre-add the user account I intend to use in the Azure AD B2C user list. I'd like to avoid this step and allow any Microsoft email to access without the need for preloading.**

I've come across several posts suggesting that this might not be possible at the moment. As an alternative solution, I'm considering logging my users into Microsoft using 'passport-microsoft' and then creating a corresponding user in the Cognito user pool with the Microsoft email they used to log in. However, I want to prevent users from accessing the platform both through Cognito and Microsoft simultaneously.

Is there a way to address this issue, or is there a simpler approach I should consider?

Comment: Did you look into solutions such as dynamic user creation for b2c? The users can log in with their Microsoft accounts without pre-loading them

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas Any documentation? I can't find anything

Comment: you need to go through the documentation thoroughly and you will have an idea how to implement it, its not called dynamic user creation as such, but thats my term for it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview